# Eureka Server in TCP

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, service-discovery

When I create service discovery server, it was automatically set to HTTP

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class DiscoveryServerApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}


application.properties

spring.application.name=discovery-server
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
server.port=8761
```

http://localhost:8761/eureka

is it possible to set to to TCP/IP or UDP etc?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Eurkea server itself is an http server. Clients that register themselves register a host and port. There's nothing that says the port has to be an http port.

Comment: Thank you spencer